# Customize TabbedPanelHeader

Tags: python, kivy

I'm using a `TabbedPannel` in my App followed by some `TabbedPanelItem` now I want to customize them.

I went `kivy/examples/widgets/tabbed_panel_showcase.py` to see some examples of these customization.

They have there a class `StandingHeader` that inherits from `TabbedPanelItem` and then they add some extra properties:

```
class StandingHeader(TabbedPanelHeader):
    pass
<StandingHeader>
    color: 0,0,0,0
    disabled_color: self.color
    Scatter:
        do_translation: False
        do_scale: False
        do_rotation: False
        auto_bring_to_front: False
        rotation: 70
        size_hint: None, None
        size: lbl.size
        center_x: root.center_x
        center_y: root.center_y
        Label:
            id: lbl
            text: root.text
            size: root.size
            color: 1, 1, 1, .5 if self.disabled else 1
            pos: 0,0
```

I tried to reuse this code to change my `TabbedPanelItem` but it didn't work, all the labels disappeared. It seems that `TabbedPanelItem` inherits from `TabbedPanelHeader` so it should work but if I change the `StadingHeader` in the showcase example to inherit now from `TabbedPanelItem` it also stops working. So with this in mind, my question is how can I customize the `TabbedPanelItem`?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?